# C to MIPS assembly - storing an array

Tags: mips, mips32

I have the following code in C and I am trying to figure out what the MIPS equivalent is:

```
array[7] = x;
```

I know that the base address of array is stored in $a0 and the variable x is stored in $t0.

I thought it would be sw $t0, 28($a0) but that stores the entire array.

Comment: "I thought it would be sw $t0, 28($a0)" It is indeed. "but that stores the entire array" What do you mean? No instruction stores a complete array. Only a single data movement is done by an instruction. Can you precise your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sb $t0, 7($a0)
```

This is the answer